# What's the best way to play music from my iPhone in my car wirelessly?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, music

I have an iPhone 4 (and have pre-ordered a 4S] and I have a car.  I'd like to play the music from my phone over the car's speakers easily.  I know I can get a cord that has a cigarette lighter adapter on one end and a 3.5mm audio jack on the other but I'd prefer to do it completely wireless if possible.

Has anyone had any success doing this?  If so what device(s) did you use?

Comment: Note that you _can't_ plug your phone into a cigarette lighter plug and have it play on the speakers. The cigarette lighter plug just supplies power - it's not connected to the audio system in any way. You'd need a different kind of adapter.

Comment: You can use an FM Transmitter, but the audio quality is excruciatingly bad. If you care even remotely about the sound quality, get a deck that supports Apple's mobile device line-up. Even the cheapest and lowest end deck has iPod/iPhone support these days.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Bluetooth stereo if you want NO wires or adapters, but it constantly cuts out (check other forums). You'd be better off with a direct connection, or an adapter/cable to send it over tr FM waves

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is via [Bluetooth A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29). Basicly it's the most standard way to send stereo audio via Bluetooth.

The best case would be if you own Car stereo that has native support for A2DP and AVRCP (control your iPhone play/pause/next from your stereo). If you don't own such equipment, you could use separate A2DP receiver like [Tunelink Auto](http://newpotatotech.com/TUNELINK_AUTO/tunelink_auto.html) and connect it in your AUX in port (or receive it on FM).

ps. I would never go wireless

1. Quality is worse than wired (almost all the time).
2. While I'm on the move i prefer to have my iPhone charged.
3. There are great players that can do much more (at a price) over the wire - for example [Pioneer AppRadio](http://www.pioneerelectronics.com/PUSA/Car/AppRadio/AppRadio+%28SPH-DA01%29?sel=products).